# Do third party cooler's T.I.M. contain adheasive?

Tags: cpu, cooling, thermal-paste

I'm building my first computer, and I purchased a cheap *Thermaltake CL-P0503* cooler in a bundle. I was originally going to grab some high quality thermal paste, but I forgot to purchase some. My cooler has a pre-applied T.I.M. (thermal inference material: a pad of thermal paste type gunk) and I want to use that until I can get some Arctic Silver paste shipped to me (that is without paying $500 for overnight shipping). I also **need** to finish building my computer in the next few days to verify that it works with warranties... not to mention I can't wait for my new computer!

My main concern with using the pre-applied paste is that it is going to have some adhesive in in, since my box mentions nothing about the paste. **Is it possible to get it off?** I would assume that it wouldn't be adheasive since it would be exposed to air, but I'm concerned that it's heat activated. Is there any way to tell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it will not be adhesive.  In fact, it might be more effective than something like Arctic Silver, since it's already evenly distributed and the right amount for the chip.  Many people put too much Arctic Silver on their CPU and it spills out which is not very good for the computer.

I would not worry about the thermal pad, it's not a glue, and it will most likely work just as well if not better than Actic Silver thermal compound.

Good luck on the build!

Comment: Also, if it's going on then coming off in a couple days it's probably not going to have time to bake onto the CPU. :P